# Ionic angular encode url encoding odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app and I want to pass an object from the view to the controller via the url.

The url looks like '/baseurl/:path/:object/:title', where :path, :object, :title are parameters.

In my controller I have an object, I stringify it and run encodeUriComponent on it, this is my parameter that will be added to the :object parameter in the url.

The actual problem is that for specific objects, running encodeUriComponent on the string representation of the object result in a bad format in the url, thus corrupting my url.

When debugging, the object is encoded correctly, but it's poorly formatted only in the url when passing it from the view.

**Any ideas or tips on how it would be a best practice to pass an object from a controller to a view and from the view to another controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`ui-router`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router), you can pass parameters without specifying them in the URL like this:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    params: {
        param1: null
    }
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
```

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls for more details and usage examples.